# surface area of a cube related rates problem

Tags: derivatives

The volume of a cube is expanding at a rate of $4cm^3/s$. What is the rate the surface area is changing when the area is $24cm^2$.
What I do is:
$$
V=h^3
\\A=6h^2={6V\over{h}}
\\h=\sqrt{A\over6}=2
$$
Then...
$$
{dA\over{dt}}={6{dV\over{dt}}h\over{h^2}}={6\bullet4\bullet2\over{4}}=12cm^2/s
$$
But it says the answer is not 12. Not sure what I did wrong, havent done related rates in a long time. Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a much simpler way to do it. We can solve for $h$ as a function of $V$:
$$h=\sqrt[3]{V}$$
Plugging this into the formula for area, we have
$$A=6h^2=6V^{2/3}$$
Using the chain rule,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}V}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
We know $\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$. Can you find $\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}V}$ and take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way:

$$ V = h^3 ⇔ \frac{dV}{dh} = 3h^2 $$

$$ A = 6h^2 ⇔ \frac{dA}{dh} = 12h $$

$$ \frac{dV}{dt} = 4 $$

Therefore  $$ \frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{dA}{dh} * \frac{dh}{dV} * \frac{dV}{dt} $$

$$ \frac{dA}{dt} = 12h * \frac{1}{3h^2} * 4 $$

$$ \frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{16}{h} $$

When  Area = $24$

$$ A = 6h^2 $$

$$ 24 = 6h^2 $$

$$ h = 2 $$

$$\frac{dA}{dt}_{h=2}  = \frac{16}{h}  $$

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = 8 cm^{2}/s $$